# User email is not being retrive by sigin in with google

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I have made change in firebase authentication option related **User Account Linking**. I have Selected option *Create multiple accounts for each identity provider* now I'm not able to get user email ID when user try to sign in with google. all other details like *user.displayName*, *user.photoURL* is retrive but only *user.email* is not being retrive.

below is my code:

```
void signUpWithGoogle(context) async {
  try {

    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => Container(
        color: Colors.black,
        child: const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
    final GoogleSignInAccount? googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication = await googleSignInAccount!.authentication;

    // provider.setCustomParameters({});
    final AuthCredential authCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
        accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken);

    UserCredential result = await fireAuth.signInWithCredential(authCredential);
    globals.user = result.user;

    if(!await UserData().isUserExists(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)) {
      debugPrint("_-_-_-_-_-_ NEW USER _-_-_-_-_-_\n ${result.user} \n ${globals.user.email}\n ${globals.user.displayName}\n ${globals.user.photoURL}");
      UserData(true, globals.user.email, globals.user.displayName, globals.user.photoURL).addUser(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid);
    } else {
      debugPrint("_-_-_-_-_-_ USER ALREADY EXISTS _-_-_-_-_-_");
    }

    if(result != null) {
      Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
        // MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const HomeScreen()),(Route<dynamic> route) => false
        PageRouteBuilder(
            pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => const HomeScreen(),
            transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1500),
            transitionsBuilder: (_, a, __, c) => FadeTransition(
              opacity: a,
              child: c,
            )), (Route<dynamic> route) => false
      );
    } else {
      debugPrint(" RESULT USER IS NULL =>=>=> ");
    }
  } catch (exception) {
    if(exception is PlatformException) {
      if(exception.code == GoogleSignIn.kNetworkError) {
        showAlert(context, "You have Poor Connectivity.");
      } else {
        debugPrint("YOU HAVE EXCEPTION IN GOOGLE SIGN IN ${exception.code}");
      }
    }
    debugPrint("YOU HAVE PROBLEM IN GOOGLE SIGN IN $exception");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are referring to "Create multiple accounts for each identity provider" I'm assuming it is not just Google. I had a similar problem before with Facebook.

If you're not receiving the e-mail address of the user, there are three possible reasons i can think of. In my case (1) was the issue.

1. The account doesn't have a (verified) email address associated with it. Some platforms allow accounts to be created without an email address.
2. The identity provider doesn't provide the e-mail address because you didn't ask for the scope 'email'.
3. The email address is stored elsewhere in the return object.